# WinRT GridView with items of different size

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to use GridView with DataTemplateSelector. So some of the items are huge and some of them are small. I have two problems:

1. Big items are not fully visible. Bottom part of element is hidden. Looks like element doesn't call MeasureOverride properly.
2. Gaps between small items are to big. I'd prefer to have margins of the same size (like when using WrapPanel). Is there any ways to make WrapGid behave like WrapPanel? I don't want to use VariableSizeWrapGrid beacuse I need virtualization for my data.

Is there any way to solve that problems?

Is there any way to forse GridView to recalculate number of rows?